# center aligning text in navbar with respect to glyphicon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am creating a nav menu and finding it difficult center aligning the text under the glyphyicon. Here is my code below. Not sure if i am doing things right. It needs to be like the expected navbar

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Country <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

**Current Nav bar**

[image]

**Expected Navbar**

[image]

Comment: could you please share a fiddle or so with us..it would be really helpfull..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `text-center` in the UL `navbar`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Country <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

http://www.bootply.com/xuzJVpzuat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do this, it works for me !

```
<div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span></div>
```

You can check the code in a working fiddle: [HERE](http://www.bootply.com/EmzUMHPXqd)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I am not looking at center aligning the text in the navbar. I am looking at center aligning the text with respect to glyphicon

Comment: The text has to be center aligned under the glyphicon image

Comment: I have shared two images for you to compare

Comment: Check ZimSystem's solution, i guess it's working great :)